# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined using MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm currently attempting to display content of a collection in mongodb via a specific view. I would like to have it where if there is no content for said collection, it would just skip over but was told that's not needed with mongodb. However, when I attempt to run the following jade template, I get the error message listed above.

The js file in route that should be getting the data from the collection, empty or not.

```
router.get('/commentList', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var comments = db.get('comments');
    comments.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('commentList', {
            "commentList" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

and the code for the view in the accompying jade file

```
h2
    Comments
ul
    each comment, i in commentList
        li
            p comment.commentContent - comment.created_on - comment.author
```

the onyl thing I could see that could be causing the error is an empty collection but then how would you say "if collection is empty, do the following?" to avoid said error, assuming that's the problem?

EDIT: I'm staffed the database with content but still get the same error message, so at least it's not because the DB collection was empty.

EDIT #2: Got a question if comments was a mongo driver collection or mongoose. I'm not entirely sure (I think it's Mongoose as it created the connection), but this is how it is declared in app.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = Mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'acl');
```

EDIT #3: Tried changing the connection so it uses the mongo connection directly instead of through mongoose. Here's the code

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),Server = mongo.Server,Db = mongo.Db;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {safe:true});
var db = new Db('acl', server);
```

The error is still the same.

EDIT #4: I've scrapped this copy and have started anew due to my suspision that the cobbling of muultiple tutorials has made this a dog breakfest of code, and would be quicker to hit the reset button

Comment: `commentList` is likely undefined, so the template engine fails when it uses `arr.length` internally for iterating. Check the value of docs.

Comment: @user2864740 checked value nothing is ever showed in console, be it log or warn. then again there's nothing in the collection right now, so should a collection be defined beforehand, or is ther ea way to say "if this is blank, handle it?"

Comment: Is `comments` a MongoDB native driver collection or a Mongoose model?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I believe it's a Mongoose model. Have a look at the latest code snippet that I've uploaded to the main answer.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately that doesn't really help clarify what `req.db.get('comments')` returns.  A Mongoose connection doesn't have a `get` method that I can see.

Comment: @JohnnyHK It could be old code that I've learned from other tutorials in my travels. I'm literally learning as I go so I might have things that aren't needed. I'll try a connection without mongoose of monk or whatever and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why are you getting your db object from the request? If you're using mongoose do you have a schema? Mongoose queries are usually tied to a model object. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find while `db.get` is probably this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-get

Comment: @tony probably not. It's the only spot I have reference to mongoose so I've since ripped it out.

Comment: @canadiancreed Take a look at my answer. It assumes that `db` is a `Mongoose.Connection`. Also make sure your DB is actually connecting. And if you look at the reference URL, they define a model object with a schema. I'm not sure if mongoose is smart enough to just make one if it's not present. Good luck!

Comment: @tony Just gave yours a shot, putting back all the Mongoose that I had beforehand and no dice. I'm assuming the db is connection as the console window there isn't coughing up any error messages, nor is there any errors when executing node app.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
router.get('/commentList', function(req, res) {
  req.db.get('comments').find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('commentList', {
      commentList : docs || []
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it didn't seem to put a dent in the issue. Tried consoling out docs but it returns blank.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, try:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.model('comment', new Schema( {/*your data schema*/} );

router.get('/commentList', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var comment = db.model('comment');
    comment.find({}, function(e,docs){
        res.render('commentList', {
            "commentList" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

**Update**:

I added an explicit model definition. Ensure that your collection is called `comments`. To test this, you can open a mongodb shell and run: `use ac1; db.comments.find({})` (I assume your db name is ac1) and make sure you're getting any data you have.

Also, you try changing your connection command to: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ac1');`

**Update 2**:

You can check if the render is throwing an error by adding a callback:

```
res.render('commentList', {"commentList" : docs}, function( err, html ) {
    //Inspect err.
});
```

Comment: Still returns " Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at "each comment, i in commentList "

Comment: @canadiancreed made some updates. Hope it works! Lastly, you could try just returning the raw JSON to the browser, this would identify if the problem is in the db query or strictly in the jade template.

Comment: @canadiancreed and your error means that `commentList` isn't even empty. It's nothing. So there could be something wrong with the way you're assigning it. What is the name of your jade file?

Comment: the name of the jade file would be contentOne.jade

Comment: @canadiancreed Based on my understanding of `res.render` your jade file should be named `commentList.jade` based on your render method.

Comment: Here's an example of rendering to a page. http://runnable.com/UTlPPF-f2W1TAAEe/render-jade-with-express-for-node-js Make sure that you are setting your views directory and that render corresponds to a view.

Comment: This is what I have for rendering to the view that I want to display db data in.|

exports.contentOne = function(req, res){
 res.render('contentOne', { title: 'Content One' });
};

Also i'm wondering if maybe this isn't compatible with windows. my comsole.log does nothing, nor does attempts to show raw json (it jsut shows commands regardless of whether I escape or not in the jade files.)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating mongoose to latest version. 
I hope it will help!